# Can every ODE system be written as a single higher order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

It is well-known that, given a differential equation or order $n$, it can be written as an ODE system of first-order equations, using the change of variables $x_i = x^{(i)}$. Is the converse true? Note that I'm asking about a generic system of ODEs, not only systems of the form
$$
x_1 = x_2' \\
x_2' = x_3'\\
\vdots \\
x_n' = f(x_1,\dots, x_n)
$$